# What is meant by an 8dp square baseline grid, in Android Material Design specification?

Tags: android, google-material-design, grids

I am a newb. My question is from [this Material Design specification document](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-baseline-grids):

> All components align to an **8dp square baseline grid** for mobile,
>   tablet, and desktop.

The image at the end of the question is given as an example.

I didn't know what a baseline grid is, so from my reading of [this blog article](http://blog.invisionapp.com/design-snack-7-baseline-grids-in-web-ui-design/), I gathered that baseline grid is an underlying structure (essentially a pattern of equally-spaced horizontal lines) that helps guide the vertical spacing  and alignment of components in our design. [Example image here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/blog.invisionapp.com/uploads/2015/06/make-grid.png?ver=1).

So the question is that does the statement from Material Design spec. quoted above mean that the baselines (the mentioned horizontal lines) are spaced at a distance of 8 display pixels? **Or what does it mean? How should a layman/newbie like me understand it?**

[image]

Comment: I believe that your statement is correct - but since each cell is square the vertical lines should be kept in mind while designing as well

Comment: Yeah thanks, but why did you delete your answer? I was just going to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Because it was incorrect partially :P [This post](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/designing-faster-with-a-baseline-grid/) might help with your understanding